# Text still showing up after clearing screen in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a weather app and everything works fine up to a point. I type the city in, press enter then it gives me the information, then I click Tomorrow's Forecast button and it gives me tomorrows forecast. Then when I press the go back button it is supposed to clear the screen and take me back to the first page. It seems to do this as after pressing go back it clears the screen and I am able to get information for a different city but when I press Tomorrow's forecast for the new city it still has all the information from the previous entry and tomorrow's forecast for the new city does not show up.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
import requests
from PIL import ImageTk, Image 
import time

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('750x500')
#window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def opening():

    def format_response(weather):
        try:
            name = weather['city']['name']
            temperature_today = weather['list'][0]['main']['temp']
            desc = weather['list'][0]['weather'][0]['description']
            temp_feels = weather['list'][0]['main']['feels_like']
            humidity = weather['list'][0]['main']['humidity']
            wind_speed = weather['list'][0]['wind']['speed']

            final_str = f'City: {name} \nTemperature now: {temperature_today}°C --- feels like: {temp_feels}°C \nCondtions: {desc} \nHumidty: {humidity}% \nWind Speed: {wind_speed}m/s'

        except:
            final_str = 'There was a problem retrieving that information'

        return final_str

    def get_weather(city):

        weather_key = 'a9f553857df50650433c1577e3be6538'
        url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast'
        params = {'q': city, 'appid': weather_key, 'units': 'metric'}
        response = requests.get(url, params=params)
        weather = response.json()
        label_below['text'] = format_response(weather)

        temp_tmr = tk.Button(second_frame, font=('Bookman Old Style', 10), text="Tomorrow's Forecast", command=tomorrow)
        temp_tmr.place(relx=0.74, rely=0.88, relwidth=0.25, relheight=0.1)

    def resize_image(event):
        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height
        image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        label.config(image = photo)
        label.image = photo


    image = Image.open('img\clouds.jpg')
    copy_of_image = image.copy()
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label = tk.Label(window, image = photo)
    label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand = True)

    top_frame = tk.Frame(window, bg="#0cc961", bd=5)
    top_frame.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.15)

    city_entry = tk.Entry(top_frame, font=('Bookman Old Style', 22))
    city_entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

    enter_button = tk.Button(top_frame, font=('Bookman Old Style', 18), text="Enter", command=lambda: get_weather(city_entry.get()))
    enter_button.place(relx=0.68, relwidth=0.31, relheight=1)

    second_frame = tk.Frame(window, bg="#0cc961", bd=5)
    second_frame.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.7)

    label_below = tk.Label(second_frame, font=('Bookman Old Style', 15), anchor="nw", justify="left", bd=4)
    label_below.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    return second_frame, city_entry

opening()

second_frame, city_entry = opening()

def tomorrow():
    second_frame = tk.Frame(window, bg="#0cc961", bd=5)


    for widget in second_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.place_forget()

    def format_response2(weather):
        try:
            name2 = weather['city']['name']
            temperature_tmr = weather['list'][1]['main']['temp']
            desc_tmr = weather['list'][1]['weather'][0]['description']
            temp_feels_tmr = weather['list'][1]['main']['feels_like']
            humidity_tmr = weather['list'][1]['main']['humidity']
            wind_speed_tmr = weather['list'][1]['wind']['speed']

            final_str = f'City: {name2} \nTemperature tomorrow: {temperature_tmr}°C --- will feel like: {temp_feels_tmr}°C \nCondtions: {desc_tmr} \nHumidty: {humidity_tmr}% \nWind Speed: {wind_speed_tmr}m/s'
        except:
            final_str = 'There was a problem retrieving that information'

        return final_str


    def goback():
        for widget in second_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.place_forget()
    
        opening()

    second_frame.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.7)

    label_below2 = tk.Label(second_frame, font=('Bookman Old Style', 15), anchor="nw", justify="left", bd=4)
    label_below2.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    temp_yest = tk.Button(second_frame, font=('Bookman Old Style', 10), justify="left", text="Go back", command=goback)
    temp_yest.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.88, relwidth=0.12, relheight=0.1)

    weather_key2 = 'a9f553857df50650433c1577e3be6538'
    url2 = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast'
    params2 = {'q': city_entry.get(), 'appid': weather_key2, 'units': 'metric'}
    response2 = requests.get(url2, params=params2)
    weather2 = response2.json()
    label_below2['text'] = format_response2(weather2)
        
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is lots of code and requirements to run your code. It would be better if you can give us a short version that does not depend on any API or images and is runnable by us

Comment: I can get rid of the images but the API is integral to the program and my error so I can't remove that. It should be fine to run you just need to leave Image.open('') empty @DelriusEuphoria

Comment: Not really, your error has nothing to do with the API and the images, and your problem can be reproduced without any of those

Comment: @Josborne. Do you want to go back to or clear all?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just clear the text?

```
def goback():
  for widget in second_frame.winfo_children():
    if isinstance(widget, tk.Label):
      widget["text"] = ""
    elif isinstance(widget, tk.Entry):
      widget.delete(0, 'end')
```

Comment: That doesn't work, the info is still there for the previous city entered @Edwin Torres